# how to change windowXP theme using vb.net2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I have tried the following code but has no effect:

```
Imports system.Runtime.InteropServices

<DllImport("UxTheme.DLL", BestFitMapping:=False, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Winapi, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint:="#65")> _
     Shared Function SetSystemVisualStyle(ByVal pszFilename As String, ByVal pszColor As String, ByVal pszSize As String, ByVal dwReserved As Integer) As Integer
     End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'This code will set Window Themes
        SetSystemVisualStyle("C:\WINDOWS\Resources\Themes\HmmXP_2_0_1\HmmXP\HmmXP.msstyles", "NormalColor", "NormalSize", 0)
    End Sub
```

Can anyone plz help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/windows-forms/19414-can-i-disable-windows-theme-my-form.html), may be that can be helpful to you...